# regular expression to find content within square brackets, but with some exceptions:

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression to find content within square brackets, but with some exceptions:

E.g.,

```
[abc]   -> It should match
['abc'] -> it should not match
[$abc]  -> it should not match
[integer] Like [0]  -> it should not match
```

I have used this regular expression

```
\[((?!')[^]]*)\]
```

It is working for the first 2 condition but not for the other 2  condition.

Comment: You will need to define what exactly is allowed between brackets. Why is `abc` legal and not `0`?

Comment: [0] is integer it can be any integer

Comment: Please be precise. What *exactly* is allowed between the brackets?

Comment: @nitinjain so can a matching string contain any digits? No digits? You'll only get the right regular expression if you tell people what you want to match.

Comment: Would you want to match `[1a]` or `[a1]`? Neither of them are integers.

Comment: Yes they are not integer so it should match

Comment: Then the accepted answer isn't what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex could do the job,

```
\[([^'$\d]+?)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/9)

**Explanation:**

- `\[` Matches a literal `[` symbol.
- `()` Capturing group
- `[^'$\d]+?` Matches any character not of literal `'` or `$` or `\d` one or more times. `?` after `+` does a reluctant(non-greedy) match.
- `\]` Matches a literal `]`  symbol.

Comment: Careful, in a string `foo [bar] baz [bam] boom`, it will match `[bar] baz [bam]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `$` to your negative lookahead assertion and assert that no integer number can be matched:

```
\[((?!['$]|\d+\])[^]]*)\]
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[       # Match [
(        # Capture in group 1:
 (?!     # unless the following matches here: Either...
  ['$]   # one of the characters ' or $
 |       # or
  \d+\]  # a positive integer number, followed by ]
 )       # End of lookahead assertion
 [^]]*   # Match any number of characters except closing brackets
)        # End of group 1
\]       # Match ]
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/uM3rS5/1).

Comment: sorry i forgot to put 4 condition. Its working for first 3 condition

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to avoid the negative lookahead altogether:

```
\[[^]'$\d]*\]
```